# Is gravity a natural manifestation of universal egoism?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-religion, existence, self

What bothers me is the possibility that egoism could be an intrinsic trait of existence in general.
So we have gravity whereby masses pull each other towards themselves.
An objection could be that this is just a neutral physical law, a structural feature of life evolving on this planet, devoid of any notion of "evil". 
But is it, really?
We could analogously label as "beneficial" all scholarly pursuits and creative endeavors in art, science and philosophy.
But what bothers me is the conception of trained, skillful drivers masterfully driving their vehicles off some cliff or to some similar dead end. 
So is the old problem of "the fall of man" meaningful for some branch of modern philosophy or is it universally silenced as insufficiently well-defined?

Comment: Same charges repel each other, whereas different charges attract each other - what makes you think you can apply this "physical law" to existence in general, especially when there are other physical laws you completely fail to take into consideration?

Comment: @LDM -- I think that gravity is different in that it exhibits only attraction and not repulsion. It also feels like a mysterious property of space itself. We live and die in it, we take it  for granted but its deeper sources are unkown, even in a general relativity framework, which describes it but does not explain it. And, pardon me, I am not here proposing a general theory taking all physical laws into consideration!

Comment: Define “universal egoism”.

Comment: @Just Some Old Man -- if the adjective "universal" causes a problem, you can omit it and keep only plain egoism.

Comment: @exp8j There is likely sloppy thinking behind the concept if "universal" can be omitted without much loss in meaning.

Comment: @Just Some Old Man -- I don't think so. We can equally well say "universal gravity" or just plain "gravity".

Comment: @exp8j If someone used "universal gravity" in conversation with me when he meant "gravity", I would hypothesize sloppy thinking on his part.

Comment: @Just Some Old Man -- in the context of the history of physics, it is well-known that after Newton's breakthrough the words "gravity" and "universal gravitation" became synonymous.

Comment: Of course you're free to make such comparative analogies and believe their common metaphysical link. However, it's equally possible there's another kind of analogies since now in cosmology we know dark energy is the most powerful hidden propulsion of this universe and still keeps its expansion. Then the opposite metaphysical link can be argued for...

Comment: @Double Knot -- Yes, metaphysical analogies are not hard facts and can be reversed, but at least the possibility of some link is raised which may not be entirely nonsensical. But why does the expanding universe argue for the opposite of egoism? Galaxies are moving away from each other, each withdrawing in its own world, probably having a black hole in its center...

Comment: Blackholes are like dark matter, can only pull things in, not outward... We can perhaps only know our metaphysics about egoism as something *universal* from these 2 "opposite direction" contingent universal physical phenomena if you go the idealism route, however, there're many other (necessary) things universal like logic, math. What else useful thing you can arrive at from these analogies regarding egoism?

Comment: @exp8j I have a degree in physics with research published. I have never once heard "universal gravity". More importantly, I think, kindly, you are resisting obvious reasons for downvotes and votes for closure. A blade of grass can be seen to be long and slender, and the duration of time between 1700 and 1800 can be seen to be long and slender, therefore, time is a "natural manifestation" of universal grassiness. Tenuous, stretched, try-hard analogies and metaphors are not ripe for analysis because sound reasoning demands some clarity.

Comment: @Double Knot --My concern is how seriously I should take the "fall of man" parable and the accompanying idea of the "fall of nature as a whole". I feel I should be alert to the possibility that my scholarly interests are a waste of time even if they come from "deep inside my heart". That's why I mentioned those drivers driving skillfully to a dead end. They have mastered their art, but from a wider perspective, it's the direction they follow that is problematic, full of egoism. From there I expanded it to ..cosmic dimensions!.. Just expressing some psychological issues I occassionaly have.

Comment: @Just Some Old Man -- well I'm not saying that all analogies have equal merits but time as universal grassiness is something indeed!:) As for "universal gravity" I'm puzzled by what you say, it's quite common as "universal gravitation". Is there a problem with the word "gravity" vs "gravitation"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_universal_gravitation

Comment: You've really touched another deeper perennial philosophical question, and Gautama Buddha might sat under the bodhi tree thinking about these universal analogies and conundrums by looking at the sky similar as you... The answer obviously again lies in your intellectual school of philosophy...

Comment: @Double Knot -- confessing egoism at least feels good... it could also be a source of ..anti-gravity!:)

Comment: Sounds on the right track... Confessing egoism is itself a metaphysical core of the old famous Eastern Confucianism school of philosophy, they advocated confessing at least 3 times every day...

Answer (score 5):

Gravity has nothing whatsoever to do with a philosophical treatment of the condition of humanity. Anyone searching for such a connection is digging a dry well.

Comment: But we are born, live and die within a gravity field! How can this have nothing to do with the condition of humanity? I think that poetic analogies do have philosophical value even in our era of quantitative science. Like Dante's well-known 'Love that moves the sun and the other stars'.

Comment: those analogies might have poetic value but they have no value at all within the scope of physics. Can you write down the equation describing exactly how much love is needed to move a star of a given size?

Comment: 'no value at all within the scope of physics'. Agreed. But how about value within the scope of philosophy?